# The OpenStreetMap tile layer image was not displayed when added in Image control in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, openstreetmap, bitmapimage, openmaptiles

I was trying to display the image of **tile layer for OpenStreetMap** using the Image control in the UWP platform, but the tile layer was displayed or displayed blank.

Here is my code.

In the MainPage.xaml file, I have created a simple Image control.

```
<Page
    x:Class="BitmapImageDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BitmapImageDemo"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="image"
               Stretch="Uniform" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In the MainPage.xaml.cs file, I have initialized a new BitMapImage control and set the OSM tilelayer’s URI   to its UriSource property. Later set the bitMapImage to the Image.Source.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/1/1/0.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        image.Width = bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 256;
        image.Height = bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 256;
        image.Source = bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

You can find/download the example sample from the following [github link](https://github.com/VishalOmprasad/test-samples/blob/main/BitmapImageDemo.zip).

I have checked with Uri's of some other images and it got displayed, but the OSM tile layer image was not displayed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Requesting a tile needs some requirements. Including valid user-agent. You'll find the requirments here : https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/    You can use fiddler or similar software to check if your request has a correct user-agent

Answer (score 0):

Openstreetmap tiles can be used in `Mapcontrol` with [HttpMapTileDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.httpmaptiledatasource?view=winrt-22621). If you want to display tiles in Image control, you need to download them in advance. The following code sample uses [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient?view=winrt-22621) to download image in the `image_Loaded` event.

```
<Image x:Name="image" Stretch="Uniform" Loaded="image_Loaded"/>
```

---

```
private async void image_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = sender as Image;
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    image.Source = bitmapImage;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/1/1/0.png"));

            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
                {
                    var inputStream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
                    await stream.WriteAsync(inputStream);
                    stream.Seek(0);
                    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```